# Entity framework select clause on a dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to have a select clause on a dbcontext.set. I have the following code that returns all coinsurance of People in a db table and selects all columns.

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Person>();                
}
```

I only want to select username and email

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var projection = GetPeople().Select(p => new {p.Username, p.Email});
```

Answer (score 2):

In both your example, and Jason's example, you should be aware of the fact that you are passing the context-aware object.  Further manipulations of data may cause unexpected hits against the database.  Also when you are doing a function like DbContext.Set() you are doing the slowest form of database call in EF.  For the fastest and most effecient database call you would do as follows:

```
 public List<GetPersonResult> GetPeople()
 {
       return (from p in dbContext.People
              select new GetPersonResult
              {
                   UserName = p.Username,
                   EmailAddress = p.Email
              }).ToList();
 }

 public class GetPersonResult
 {
       public string UserName{get;set;}
       public string EmailAddress{get;set;}
 }
```

Raw SQL is the fastest form of EF use.  Almost as fast as raw ADO.NET.

Comment: how is `context.People` different than `context.Set<Person>()`? `context.People` is a just a property encapsulating `Set<Person>()`. It is not more or less effecient. if you mean linq syntax is more like sql than linq extensions, then you are mistaken. linq syntax is just syntax-sugar for linq extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Person>().Select(per => new {per.UserName, per.Email})                
}
```

and you want to filter resaults, add some overloads for example:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Person>().Select(per => new {per.UserName, per.Email})                
}

public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople(int cityId)
{
    return DbContext.Set<Person>().Where(p => p.CityID == cityId)
               .Select(per => new {per.UserName, per.Email})                
}
```

Comment: `GetPeople()` method will throw an error because it should return `IQueryable<Person>` but `Select` returns anonymous type. So you need to change `.Select(per => new {per.UserName, per.Email});` to `.Select(per => new Person {per.UserName, per.Email});`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the object person :

Add a constructor in the "Person" class

```
    public Person(string UserName, string EmailAddress){
      This.UserName = UserName;
      This.EmailAddress = EmailAddress;}
```

And modify this method

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Person>()
                    .Select(per => new Person(per.UserName, per.Email));                 
}
```

Comment: `GetPeople()` method will throw an error because it should return `IQueryable<Person>` but `Select` returns anonymous type. So you need to change `.Select(per => new {per.UserName, per.Email});` to `.Select(per => new Person {per.UserName, per.Email});`

Comment: Thank you, you're right @Max. While writing the post, I forgot to call the constructor that I've implemented above.